# Increasing exhaust fan duct size

Tags: ventilation, ducts, exhaust-fan

I have a bathroom exhaust fan that has a 3 inch duct outlet. However, I would like to use a 4 inch insulated flexible duct.

Is there an adapter I can use to accomplish this or do I have to first use a short run of 3 inch duct and then use a 3-inch to 4-inch increaser?

Comment: [Seems](https://www.lowes.com/pd/IMPERIAL-4-in-dia-x-3-in-dia-Duct-Reducer/3134353) like [they're](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B005XU3QCQ/ref=asc_df_B005XU3QCQ5168146/?tag=hyprod-20&creative=394997&creativeASIN=B005XU3QCQ&linkCode=df0&hvadid=167138746282&hvpos=1o2&hvnetw=g&hvrand=16027801773590927912&hvpone=&hvptwo=&hvqmt=&hvdev=c&hvdvcmdl=&hvlocint=&hvlocphy=9020100&hvtargid=pla-306797334876) readily [available](http://www.homedepot.com/p/4-in-To-3-in-Round-Reducer-R4X3/100149942). Is there more to the question?

Comment: Those don't fit over the actual outlet on the fan.

Comment: This is the actual fan I have: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Hampton-Bay-70-CFM-No-Cut-Ceiling-Mount-Exhaust-Bath-Fan-BPT13-13D-1/300068932

Comment: You'll have to use some DIY-foo. A slice along the sleeve and a pipe clamp or sheet metal screws would do. It's not the Lunar Excursion Module, after all. :)

Comment: The one you linked to from Home Depot is one of the ones I purchased, but it has the same 3-inch diameter as the fan's outlet vent. I also purchased a reducer that had the 3 inch end crimped but that was just a bit too tight fitting into the outlet vent and would block the damper from opening when the fan is turned on.

Comment: If you are expecting better performance, it is best to go with rigid ductwork. Most people opt to go flex, and the big box stores sell it by the truckload, but the effects of flex vs rigid is amazing. I might look for some information on this as well since I'd wager that 4" flex is worse than 3" rigid

Comment: Nope, not doing this for performance. The ducting is only for a small 70CFM fan that's just in the water closet but all of the smallest insulated ducting in my area I could find was 4inch so I just needed to increase my 3 inch vent output to a 4inch. The main part of the bathroom has another 150CFM fan with a 6 inch vent outlet so I should be ok.